# SSRS Error :Could not find stored procedure 'IsSegmentedChunk'

Tags: sql, report, ssrs

Open SSRS Reports we receive this error (sometimes)

(When opening reports or developing reports)

An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. (rsReportServerDatabaseError)
Could not find stored procedure 'IsSegmentedChunk'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEPkG.png)

Comment: What are you doing? How did you define the procedure? Have you tried to restart the product?

Comment: we reboot the product and server.
just sql query and simple ssrs reports.

Comment: Please, edit your question to describe what you were doing (not a good practice to put only the error text). Is this a new report you're building or an existent one that stopped working suddenly? if you use a query on the report instead of calling a stored procedure does it work?

Comment: I edited the question